# The text of the search bar disappears when switching between tabs. Should this be fixed?

Tags: feature-request, search

On Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites, I've noticed that the text of the search bar disappears when switching from one tab to another.

For example, if I type `javascript multiple inheritance` in the search bar on the front page of Stack Overflow, and then switch to the "Tags" tab or "Unanswered" tab, the text in the search bar disappears.

I think Stack Overflow's user interface would be significantly improved if the text of the search bar was retained when switching from one tab to another. It would make it easier to find relevant information without typing the same text over and over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any reason to retain the text, except on the search results page. And that's already available on the search page: there are four tabs below the search bar to sort the results by relevance, age, votes or activity.

Each main "tab" on the page (reached via the questions, tags, etc. buttons)  is a separate page load.

Comment: Your assumption appears to be incorrect: If I go to [this search results page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=java), and then click on the "unanswered" tab or the "tags" tab, the search query still disappears. The search results pages do not retain the text at all when switching from one tab to another.

Comment: No, not when switching tabs on the search results page.

Comment: It doesn't appear to work that way on the search results page that I posted above. Which specific search results page are you referring to?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: it keeps the search text if you switch tabs _below_ the search bar. The buttons above (Qs, Tags, Users, etc.) get you out of "search mode".

Comment: @Mat You should post this as a separate answer, since it solves the problem completely. I didn't notice them at first because they were grayed-out.